# Can the ratio comparison test work for this case?

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove whether the series, $\sum \frac{1}{n\sqrt{n+1}}$, converges or diverges. My intuition is that I want to convert this into $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2}}$ and do the comparison with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3}}$. So then I can say $\frac{a_n}{b_n} = \frac{\sqrt{n^3}}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2}} = \frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}} = \frac{1}{1+0}$. So is it legal to say that the series diverges since $\frac{1}{n}$ diverges?

Comment: First of all, the title of your post seemingly has nothing to do with the approach you've described

Comment: Second, you are right to compare $\sum \frac 1{\sqrt{n^3 + n^2}}$ to $\sum \frac 1{\sqrt{n^3}}$, but it is strange that you decide to compare this to $\sum \frac 1n$.

Comment: Have you learned about the "integral test"? Have you learned about the "$p$-test"?

Comment: It is not legal, and police are coming to arrest you.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't sure how to word it other than say that it is a variation of the harmonic series. Is there a better way to word this?

Comment: I am not allowed to use the integral test yet.

Comment: @TreausreDragon What you are doing is usually referred to as the "comparison test" (more specifically, the limit comparison test). The ratio test for convergence refers specifically to testing a sum $\sum_n a_n$ by considering the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$, which is the limit of the **ratio** of successive terms.

Comment: Oh my. Yes I did mean the comparison test I do apologize. I was thinking of convergence because that's what I wanted to prove so bad!

Comment: @TreausreDragon No need to apologize, I'm glad to see we're on the same page

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that avoids the integral test or the "$p$-test", which is typically presented as a corollary to the integral test.

Note that the sum
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}\cdot (\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n})}
$$
is a convergent [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series). Using the limit comparison test, deduce that $\sum_n \frac 1{\sqrt{n^3}}$ is also a convergent series, which in turn implies that your original sum is a convergent series.

Answer (score 0):

Ratio test didn't work here.  In general when ratio $\to 1$, the test doesn't give an answer.  This series is convergent by the integral test.  Compare to $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x+1}}$.

Comment: Is there another test I can use besides the integral test?

Comment: Off hand I can't think of any.  General statement. $\sum \frac{1}{n^x}$ converges for $x\gt 1$, diverges for $x\le 1$.